# Ошибка Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING, библиотека Gson, приложение android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Возникает ошибка Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 11 path $. при попытке обработки json с сервера в приложении.
Код (тестовый):

```
String mainJson = "{\"key1\": \"value1\"}";
Gson g = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, AppData>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, AppData> map = g.fromJson(mainJson, type); // Ошибка
```

Класс AppData:

```
public class AppData {
    public String key1;
}
```

Что странно, такая ошибка возникла и на другом json может что-то не так с самой библиотекой, вот импорт в gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Comment: у вас же один объект, а вы хотите мапу объектов из него получить

Comment: `\"value1\"` строка, а вы просите объект `AppData` - Gson не знает как его сделать из этой строки. Поясните что вы вообще хотите сделать. Вариант решения зависит от задачи - можно парсить в `Map<String, String>`, непосредственно в `AppData`, можно написать и указать конвертер для целых типов или конкретных полей.

Comment: Ответа Elizaveta'ы мне более чем достаточно, задача просто вывести различные записи с сервера, который отправляет json